# Moving gradle build to another machine

Tags: windows, gradle, firewall, portability

It seems that when Gradle 3.1 downloads the dependencies for your project it stores them in:

C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches

I tried copying the contents of this folder to a different machine that has a fresh Gradle 3.1 installation, but when I try to build my project it still tries to download all of the dependencies from scratch, which then fails because the new machine has no internet connection.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Have you found the solution of it?  I am getting the same problem. If you solved this please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Compress main folder C:\Users\username.gradle to gradleHome.zip
2. Copy and uncompress this gradleHome.zip file to another folder for example D:\gradle_home
3. set [gradle_home](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.tr/2010/09/gradle-goodness-changing-gradle-user.html) environment variable to this new folder. See how to change environment variables in windows here.[enter link description here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this. I think the GRADLE_HOME variable should point to the Gradle Bin folder. Nonetheless I tried pointing it to my home folder where the .gradle folder is and that didn't change anything when I tried to build my project.